# Ajax File Upload on File select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I have a ajaxForm jQuery library to do the task have created a sample script as given below:

**HTML & JS**

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }
#progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
#bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
#percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Ajax File Upload Demo</h1>

<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" size="60" name="myfile" id="myfile">
     <input type="submit" value="Ajax File Upload">
 </form>

 <div id="progress">
        <div id="bar"></div>
        <div id="percent">0%</div >
</div>
<br/>

<div id="message"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{


 $('#myfile').change(function(){

    var options = {
url: "doajaxfileupload.php",
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        $("#progress").show();
        //clear everything
        $("#bar").width('0%');
        $("#message").html("");
        $("#percent").html("0%");
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete)
    {
        $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
        $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

    },
    success: function()
    {
        $("#bar").width('100%');
        $("#percent").html('100%');

    },
    complete: function(response)
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
    },
    error: function()
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='red'> ERROR: unable to upload files</font>");

    }

};

     $("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);

});
});

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

No Here, this script works fine when form is submitted using the Submit button.

But I tried the file upload on click/change of file upload button, to upload the file right away without clicking the submit button, but it didn't work.

Ofcourse it doesn't work because the `$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);` process on form submit.

Now what could be done in this script to make my requirement work. Please guide.

Comment: did you try with `$("#myForm").ajaxForm(options).submit()` or `trigger('submit')` ?

Comment: you mean inside the same script? And how to use `trigger('submit')`?

Comment: I have removed the `PHP` tag and the `PHP` source because it is working and isn't relevant to solving the client side issues. Just to simplify the question.

Comment: `$("#myForm").ajaxForm(options).submit()` or `$("#myForm").ajaxForm(options).trigger('submit')` in your ` $('#myfile').change(function(){})` (at the end you have this but without submit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `$("#myForm").ajaxForm(options);` to:

```
$("#myForm").ajaxSubmit(options);
```

See the working [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cHpDa/).

**Reason for this change:**
You need to use `ajaxSubmit` so you can manage the events in your `options`. `ajaxForm` does not allow you to bind the events because it is 'managed'.

> Use ajaxSubmit if you want to bind your own submit handler to the form.
>
> Use ajaxForm when you want the plugin to manage all the event binding for you.

(Source: Comments in the Ajax Form JQuery Plugin)

---

This is using the [Ajax Forms jQuery Plugin](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js). Your HTML has two links to jQuery, should one of them not be to the jQuery forms plugin?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.form.js"></script>
```